# swapping multiple fxml pages on the stage in JavaFX

Tags: java, controller, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Having gone through about all the answers related to my posted question, i was able to get the desired result but my first fxml was missing some details. After rectifying it, the second fxml page has refused to load. My first fxml page has got a button while the second fxml is a simple login page. I would appreciate any detailed assistance because I've been battling with it for like a week trying various codes.

**TestPatch.java**

```
public class TestPatch extends Application {    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("WinSecHome.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);                  
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
}
```

**First controller**

```
public class WinSecAdminLoginController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    TextField usernameInput;
    @FXML
    PasswordField passwordInput;
    @FXML
    Button loginButtton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void loginAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }    
}
```

**Second Controller**

```
public class WinSecHomeController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Button button;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void buttonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("WinSecAdminLogin.fxml"));/* Exception */
        Stage stage = new Stage();   
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }    
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you can share the fxml files and the code you tried.

Comment: Please provide many more details. Which other questions have you referenced? What precisely are you trying to do? If possible, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem: explain what you expect it to do and what happens that is different to that. As your question stands, it is almost impossible to provide any help.

Comment: Having successfully loading the first fxml on the stage, i want to load the login page upon clicking the "enter" button